# Applying a (cosine) similarity measure - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cosine-similarity

I have 2 pandas dataframe of shape:

```
df.shape (1,8) 

df1.shape (14,8)
```

I'd like to calculate cosine_similarity of df with each row in df1. Here's some sample data:

[image: data]

Attempting to do something similar to like this, where row is values in each row:

```
def cosine_calc(row_arr):
    
    val = cosine_similarity(df.iloc[0].values, row_arr)
    
    return val

  # Apply function
  dfComp['Cosine_val'] = dfComp.apply(lambda x: cosine_calc(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_similarity(df.values, df1.values)
```

Testcase:
Cosine similarity of an matrix (array of vectors) with itself should be symmetric

```
assert np.all(
    cosine_similarity(df1.values, df1.values) - 
    cosine_similarity(df1.values, df1.values).T == 0)
```